# how to configure log4j logs in AWS amazon linux tomcat8

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I have manually deployed my application on tomcat8 in aws EC2 (amazon linux type:t2.micro) and tried configuring log4j logs. The settings same works in my local computer windows tomcat8, but in aws EC2, the log file (abctest.log) is not getting created.

tried giving relative paths for the file and created a techincal case with AWS.